# How to get img src to change by getting id from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing trouble in getting the attributes in itemIMG to change when the button is clicked.

This is the code in my js, it is in a loop:

```
$("#btnitemIMGcolour").click(function(){
    $("#itemIMG").attr("src", serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemColour);
}
```

This is the code for the button to function window.location:

```
$('#btnitemIMGcolour' + arr[i].colourID).bind("click", {id1: arr[i].itemID, id2: arr[i].colourID}, function (event) { //This line of code create a button and has an event listener
     var data = event.data;
     displayothercolour(data.id1, data.id2); // Call shoecat function
});

function displayothercolour(itemID,colourID) {
   window.location = "itemdetail.html?itemID=" + itemID + "&colourID=" + colourID;
   localStorage.setItem("colourID", colourID);
}
```

The codes works, however the image currently only show the latest image inserted in the database.

The full loop is shown below:

```
function _getitemcolour(arr) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $("#btnitemIMGcolour").click(function () {
            $("#itemIMG").attr("src", serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemColour);
        }
        var t;
        t = "<a href='#' id='btnitemIMGcolour" + arr[i].colourID + "'> <img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemColour + "' class='itemIMGcolour'>";
        $("#itemIMGcolour").append(t);
        $('#btnitemIMGcolour' + arr[i].colourID).bind("click", { id1: arr[i].itemID, id2: arr[i].colourID }, function (event) { //This line of code create a button and has an event listener
            var data = event.data;
            displayothercolour(data.id1, data.id2); // Call shoecat function
        });
    }
}

function displayothercolour(itemID, colourID) {
    window.location = "itemdetail.html?itemID=" + itemID + "&colourID=" + colourID;
    localStorage.setItem("colourID", colourID);
}
```

Comment: Where is `i` defined and assigned?

Comment: Probably a problem with a closure. Could you please post the full loop?

Comment: Use `let i` instead of `var i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @Szab Hi, i have posted the full loop. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

So, first of all you've a got a little syntax error 6, i.e. your code is missing enclosing ')' (parenthesis). So that whole part should look like this:

```
$("#btnitemIMGcolour").click(function () {
     $("#itemIMG").attr("src", serverURL() + "/images/" + arr[i].itemColour);
})
```

Second of all. There's no point in splitting the variable declaration and initialisation - you can do both at once. E.g. instead of this:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    /* Rest of the code */
}
```

you can simply do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    /* Rest of the code */
}
```

And the same can be done with variable 't'. And finally to the point. Your `img.src` always contains the same value because of something called a closure. Without getting into details: when you create a function inside of a function, the variables from the parent function used in a child function are not copied to the child function, but they are referenced as if there were declared inside that function. Let's consider the example below:

```
var value = 0;
var counter1 = function() {
    value = value + 1;
    return value;
};
var counter2 = function() {
    value = value + 1;
    return value;
};
counter1(); // returns 1
counter2(); // returns 2
counter1(); // returns 3
counter2(); // returns 4
```

Whenever a `counter1` or a `counter2` function is called, they update and return a value of the same variable - that's because that variable was *referenced* in a function instead of its value being simply copied inside those functions. The same happens in your code - the `click` handler references the `i` variable, so when its finally called as a result of a click event, it uses the "current" (or actually the last) value of `i` which is equal to the index of the last element in an array.

To overcome that problem, you can simply create another function which accepts a value of `arr[i]` as an argument and performs all the operations inside:

```
function bindEvents(item) {
    $("#btnitemIMGcolour").click(function () {
        $("#itemIMG").attr("src", serverURL() + "/images/" + item.itemColour);
    });
    var t = "<a href='#' id='btnitemIMGcolour" + item.colourID + "'> <img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" + item.itemColour + "' class='itemIMGcolour'>";
    $("#itemIMGcolour").append(t);
    $('#btnitemIMGcolour' + item.colourID).bind("click", { id1: item.itemID, id2: item.colourID }, function (event) { //This line of code create a button and has an event listener
        var data = event.data;
        displayothercolour(data.id1, data.id2); // Call shoecat function
    });
}

function _getitemcolour(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        bindEvents(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

More about closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

More about closures and loops: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?noredirect=1&lq=1)